# How to parse XML string instead of XML file with libxml++

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I'm trying to parse a string containing an XML doc in my C++ program. I know I can do this with [C using libxml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554792/how-to-parse-a-xml-string-instead-of-xml-doc-in-c-using-libxml2-library) but I would like a C++ solution using libxml++ (which is built on top of libxml2).

Currently, I can parse from a file like so:

```
DomParser *parser = new DomParser;
parser->parse_file("sample.xml");
```

Comment: According to the docs there is a function to parse a string just like the function that parses a file: https://developer.gnome.org/libxml++/stable/classxmlpp_1_1DomParser.html#abe6b1966f057085047b7bc64ca3f064a

Comment: @Galik hmm not sure how I missed that... I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple (almost identical to parsing a file).

```
parser->parse_memory(xml_document);
```

In my case I needed the option to support both so this is the solution I came up with.

```
ifstream input_stream;
input_stream.open(xml.c_str(), ios::in); // attempt to open the file for reading 
if(input_stream.fail())
{
    parser->parse_memory(xml); // is not a file, parse as a string
} 
else
{
    parser->parse_file(xml); // is a file, parse as a file
}
```